# Best way to authenticate an Azure Automation Powershell script

Tags: powershell, authentication, azure-automation, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to implement a fairly simple PowerShell query, hosted in Azure Automation, to manage External Identities

I've set up a System Managed Identity and have successfully connected using `Connect-AzAccount -Identity`

But when I run it, it says `You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets`

The next cmdlet is `Get-AzureADPolicy`, which I think triggered the above message

Following [this blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61313906/is-it-possible-authenticate-both-connect-azaccount-and-connect-azuread-using-mfa), I tried this:

```
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext -ErrorAction Stop
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $AzureContext.Tenant.TenantId -AccountId $AzureContext.Account.Id
```

and I get this: `Unable to find an entry point named 'GetPerAdapterInfo' in DLL 'iphlpapi.dll'`

Am not at all sure now what to do; any help appreciated

PS: I'm aware there are quite few related questions, but I have not been able to find an answer to this particular query ...

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and I resolved it by using the below commands. I have added comments to underline what each statement is meant for.

```
# Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook. Out-Null is used to disable any output from this Cmdlet.

Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process | Out-Null

# Connect to Azure with system-assigned managed identity.

$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context

# set and store context. Out-Null is used to disable any output from this Cmdlet.

Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext | Out-Null
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I have (or rather what I start with), but - per above - I have also to use Connect-AzureAD - and this is what is causing problems; I am in discussion with M/S support, and will revert here if we get a resolution

Answer (score 1):

With help from M/S support, I can now clarify the issue. The core point is that it is *not* possible to authenticate for AzureAD (with Connect-AzureAD) using Managed Identity;  a Run As account must be used, at least currently

Further, for our use case, the Run As account had to have "Global Admin" role; "Owner" was not sufficient

It *is* of course possible to use Managed Identity for managing *other* Azure Resources (using Connect-AzAccount)